# Memory Leak with setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, memory-leaks

I'm currently having an issue with what in belive is a memory leak on a custom PHP website that utilises JS SetInterval

My site loads values from an external PHP file every 30 seconds and appends them to a HTML object, a `<p>` tag in this case.

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {

setInterval (function foo1(){

     $.get("scriptref.php", function( data ) { //receiving the echo from the php data file
          $("#ref").html(data); //putting the echoed value directly into the p tag
       });

    return foo1;
}(), 30000)});
    </script>
```

I also have a countdown timer that counts downwards in seconds to a specified value.

```
<script>

                    var timer = document.getElementById("demo");

                    var snd = new Audio("/assets/audio/horn.wav"); // buffers automatically when created



                    // Update the count down every 1 second
                    var x = setInterval(function() {

                        var jsnextbreach = document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML;



                        // Set the date we're counting down to
                        var countDownDate = new Date(jsnextbreach).getTime();

                        // Get todays date and time
                        var now = new Date().getTime();

                        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
                        var distance = countDownDate - now;

                        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                        // If the count down is over, write some text 
                        if (distance < 0) {

                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "BREACHED";
                        }

                        // If the count down is less than an hour replace demo class to warning. 
                        if (distance < 3600000 ) { 
                        timer.className = "warning" ;

                        }

                        if (distance > 3600001 ) { 
                        timer.className = "normal" ;

                        }

                        if (distance < 3600000 && distance > 3598000) { 

                        snd.play();

                        }


                        },1000);






                    </script>
```

My problem is that after the page is displayed for an hour or so i get the "Aw snap, google chrome ran out of memory while trying to display this webpage" error. Looking at the profiler I can see that memory usage increases slowly, however I have no idea where to start looking to find out what is causing this leak.

If anyone is able to advise anything that may be wrong with my code or alternatively how i can start troubleshooting what specific element is causing the leak i would be truly grateful!